# I want to fetch data in sequence of their branched data if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have data in one table as Question Table

```
QuestionID  QuestionDescription
2           This is test
3           test is tst
4           3
6           5
17          6
18          7
19          8
20          9
5           4
```

and in one Table QuestionBranching Table as

```
QuestionBranchingID QuestionID  Response    NextQuestionID  ParentQuestionID
1                      3        True        5               3
2                      3        False       6               3
7                      5        True        19              3
8                      5        False       20              3
9                      18       True        17              18
10                     18       False       4               18
```

So if any QuestionID exists in the QuestionBranching table then the Select Join query should fetch data in that sequence order. for ex.:
If QuestionID exists in QuestionBranching Table then NextQuestionID will be next in the sequence. 
and If not then normal flow.

So the desired result i am looking for is :

```
QuestionID
2
3(if it exists in QuestionBranching then NextQuestionID will be next i.e. '5')
5
6
19
20
18
17
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select isnull(b.NextQuestionID,q.QuestionID) as QuestionID
from Question q
left join QuestionBranching b on q.QuestionID=b.QuestionID
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the quick reply.

This is returning :
QuestionID
2
5
6
4
6
17
18
19
20
19
20

Comment: I want QuestionID first then NextQuestionID of that one in the sequence.

And also if That NextQuestionID also has entry in QuestionBranching table then it should be in that flow (for ex. Question 5 has 19 and 20 so they should come after 5 in the flow.

Comment: ok, this is much harder. You'll have to use CTE recursion. Search around for this, it will take too much time for me to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
declare @question table (QuestionID int, QuestionDescription varchar(100))
declare @branching table (BranchingID int, QuestionID int, Response bit, NextQuestionID int)

insert into @question values (2, 'this is a test'), (3, 'test is tst'), (4, '3'), (6, '5'), (17, '6'), (18, '7'), (19, '8'), (20, '9'), (5, '4')
insert into @branching values (1, 3, 1, 5), (2, 3, 0, 6), (7, 5, 1, 19), (8, 5, 0, 20)

select t.nq
from   ( select q.QuestionID, q.QuestionID as nq 
         from   @question q
         union all
         select isnull((select b2.QuestionID from @branching b2 where b2.NextQuestionID = b.QuestionID), b.QuestionID) as QuestionID, b.NextQuestionID as nq
         from   @branching b
       ) t
order by t.QuestionID, t.nq
```

Comment: Thanks, This is working fine for 2 level of branching but not with 3 or more than that level.

Comment: For that you will need a recursive CTE. There are plenty of examples if you look for that

Comment: Hey, what you were trying to do with Parent QuestionID, now i am storing it(Top level Parent) in the QuestionBranching Table.

Comment: I do not understand your question